# cannot assign to property .... setter in accesible swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, mobile, get, set

I'm trying to get artist info from a web api and create a new Artist class with the returned data however I cannot set my class attributes to the returned data. Here is my code

import Foundation
class TrackList
{

```
static var trackService:TrackService?

static func getArtistFromService()-> Artist
{
    // construct the complete URL endpoint ot be called

    //let searchURL = "https://\(siteURL)/?s=\(searchTerm)"
    var searchedartist : Artist

    let searchURL = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.gettoptracks&artist=drake&api_key=d932ba18a79b1739a4d9ba02c63bdb61&format=json"

    // degugging - can test in browser if call is failing
    print ("Web Service call = \(searchURL)")

    // create the Web Service object that will make the call - initialiser
    trackService = TrackService(searchURL)

    // create an operation queue - to allow the web service to be called on a secondary thread...
    let operationQ = OperationQueue()
    //... will only allow one task at a time in queue...
    operationQ.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
    //...queue that web service object as the operation object to be run on this thread
    operationQ.addOperation(trackService!)
    //... wait for the operation to complete [Synchronous] - better to use delegation, for [Asynchronous]
    operationQ.waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished()

    // clear the current list of movies
    // get the raw JSON back from the completed service call [complete dataset]
    let returnedJSON = trackService!.jsonFromResponse

    let artist = returnedJSON?["artist"] as! String
    let bio = returnedJSON?["bio"] as! String

          searchedartist.name = artist
        searchedartist.bio = bio


    // return the main list of Movie objects to caller (UI)

    return searchedartist
}


// for debugging - displays some details of the Movies currently in the main list...
```

}  // end of class declaration

class Artist
{
     private (set)var name:String
     private (set) var bio:String

```
init?(_ n:String, _ b:String)
{
    name = n
    bio = b

}

convenience init(_ JSONObject:[String:String])
{
    let name = JSONObject["name"]!
    let bio = JSONObject["bio"]!

    self.init(name, bio)!
}
```

}

Comment: What is TrackService? and please format the code a bit so that it is displayed properly

Answer (score 2):

Your class has private setters. Just create a new artist with the returned data instead:

```
let artist = returnedJSON.....
let bio = returnedJSON.....

let searchedArtist = Artist(artist, bio)
return searchedArtist
```

Or just use your convenience init. In general I prefer having immutable model objects so I will not recommend the alternative of making your setters public.